# Array declaration and initialization

Tags: java

1)   `int[] a={1}; //correct`

---

2)

```
 int []b;
 b[]={1};   //wrong
```

Why initialization after declaration is showing compile-time error in java??

I didn't get satisfactory answer in previous related topic,so asking again.

Comment: The linked question answers it

Comment: Because the Java grammar does not allow it.

Comment: @alexis  but in case of primitive datatype this is correct then why not for array class?

Comment: Ask the language designers.

Comment: @VinodMadyalkar I don't really see how your duplicate answers it. The question is _why_ `b={1};` does not compile (assuming the typo) - not _how_ to fix it.

Comment: @AlexisC. - From the first answer of that question - *You can either use array declaration or array literal (but only when you declare and affect the variable right away, array literals cannot be used for re-assigning an array).*. That's the answer. This is Java syntax. To be fair even the question you have used has answer like  - *But "why" is immaterial ... the restriction is there, and you have to live with it.* :). Do you still think I was wrong? :)

Comment: @VinodMadyalkar Yes the answer just tells that you cannot. The question I used still provide some pointers in the comments (which I believe is what the OP is looking for). So not _"wrong"_  but not as accurate I would say.

Comment: a) The name of the variable is b, not `b[]`. b) See comment 1 from Alexis C. c) What you can do, is `b = new int [] {1}; // correct` which means, that Ramanlfc's answer isn't accurate.

Comment: @AlexisC. - Hmm.. Will try to find better / exact dups next time around :)

Comment: @VinodMadyalkar It's fine :) (BTW good luck for the mod's election!)

Comment: @AlexisC. - Thank You :)